# How to uninstall opencv 3.0 and install opencv 2.2 instead of it (on mac)?

Tags: opencv, instructions

I am now studying opencv following a textbook using opencv 2.2, I accidentally installed opencv3.0. Can anyone give me some instruction how to uninstall my old one and use opencv 2.2 instead?

Comment: don't do that at all. please *use* opencv3.0, and rather update your [tutorials](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html)

Comment: actually I encountered a compiling error using opencv3.0 (you can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926814/configuration-of-qt-to-code-in-book-opencv2-computer-vision-application-program) and I was told by the author of that book that it is due to the conflict between 2.2 and 3.0.  By the way happy independence day.

Comment: How did you install OpenCV 3.0 in your mac?

Comment: I just followed the instruction on official website.